# convert one parent and multiple identical children into xml

Tags: php, mysql, xml

hi i have a situation where i want to create an xml from some tables in mysql using php, i can get so far no problem, but my issue arises when i have multiple identical named children.

the tables i have are as follows:

bike

```
+-----+-----------+-----------+---------+
| Uid | Bike_name | Bike_year | Bike_id |
+-----+-----------+-----------+---------+
|   1 | CBR600    |      2001 |      53 |
|   2 | ZXR750    |      1995 |      27 |
|   3 | FZR1000   |      1992 |      33 |
+-----+-----------+-----------+---------+
```

unique_features

```
+-----+------------------+---------+
| Uid |     Feature      | Bike_id |
+-----+------------------+---------+
|   1 | Micron exhaust   |      27 |
|   2 | Single seat      |      27 |
|   3 | Scorpion exhaust |      53 |
|   4 | Custom paint     |      53 |
|   5 | L.E.D lights     |      53 |
|   6 | Induction kit    |      53 |
+-----+------------------+---------+
```

bike_facts

```
+-----+-----------------+-----------+--------+---------+
| Uid | nought_to_sixty | Top_speed | weight | Bike_id |
+-----+-----------------+-----------+--------+---------+
|   1 |             3.2 |       160 |    120 |      27 |
|   2 |               4 |       160 |    150 |      33 |
|   3 |             3.5 |       150 |    100 |      53 |
+-----+-----------------+-----------+--------+---------+
```

the output i want will look like:

```
<Bikes>
  <Bike>
    <Bike_id>53</Bike_id>
    <Bike_name>CBR600</Bike_name>
    <Bike_year>2001</Bike_year>
    <Bike_facts>
        <nought_to_sixty>3.5</nought_to_sixty>
        <Top_speed>150</Top_speed>
        <Weight>100</Weight>
    </Bike_facts>
    <Unique_features>
        <feature>Scorpion exhaust</feature>
        <feature>Custom paint</feature>
        <feature>L.E.D lights</feature>
        <feature>Induction kit</feature>
    </Unique_features>
  </Bike>
  <Bike>
    <Bike_id>27</Bike_id>
    <Bike_name>ZXR750</Bike_name>
    <Bike_year>1995</Bike_year>
    <Bike_facts>
        <nought_to_sixty>3.2</nought_to_sixty>
        <Top_speed>160</Top_speed>
        <Weight>120</Weight>
    </Bike_facts>
    <Unique_features>
        <feature>Micron exhaust</feature>
        <feature>Single seat</feature>
    </Unique_features>
  </Bike>
  <Bike>
    <Bike_id>33</Bike_id>
    <Bike_name>FZR1000</Bike_name>
    <Bike_year>1992</Bike_year>
    <Bike_facts>
        <nought_to_sixty>4</nought_to_sixty>
        <Top_speed>160</Top_speed>
        <Weight>150</Weight>
    </Bike_facts>
  </Bike>
</Bikes>
```

i can produce:

```
<bikes>
  <bike bike_id="27">
    <bike_name>ZXR750</bike_name>
    <bike_year>1995</bike_year>
    <bike_facts>
      <nought_to_sixty>3.2</nought_to_sixty>
      <top_speed>160</top_speed>
      <weight>120</weight>
    </bike_facts>
  </bike>
  <bike bike_id="33">
    <bike_name>FZR1000</bike_name>
    <bike_year>1992</bike_year>
    <bike_facts>
      <nought_to_sixty>4</nought_to_sixty>
      <top_speed>160</top_speed>
      <weight>150</weight>
    </bike_facts>
  </bike>
  <bike bike_id="53">
    <bike_name>CBR600</bike_name>
    <bike_year>2001</bike_year>
    <bike_facts>
      <nought_to_sixty>3.5</nought_to_sixty>
      <top_speed>150</top_speed>
      <weight>100</weight>
    </bike_facts>
  </bike>
</bikes>
```

using this code:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "Bikes");

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) 
{
  echo "Connect failed ".$mysqli->connect_error;
  exit();
}

$query = "SELECT  
b.bike_name,
b.bike_year,
b.bike_id,
f.nought_to_sixty,
f.top_speed,
f.weight
FROM Bike b
LEFT JOIN Bike_facts f on b.bike_id = f.bike_id";

$bikesArray = array();

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) 
{
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
      array_push($bikesArray, $row);
    }
  if(count($bikesArray))
  {
     createXMLfile($bikesArray);
  }
  $result->free();
}
$mysqli->close();


function createXMLfile($bikesArray)
{
  $filePath = 'bike.xml';
  $dom     = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8'); 
  $root      = $dom->createElement('bikes'); 
  for($i=0; $i<count($bikesArray); $i++)
  {
    $bikeid            =  $bikesArray[$i]['bike_id'];  
    $bike_name         =  $bikesArray[$i]['bike_name']; 
    $bike_year         =  $bikesArray[$i]['bike_year']; 
    $nought_to_sixty   =  $bikesArray[$i]['nought_to_sixty']; 
    $top_speed         =  $bikesArray[$i]['top_speed']; 
    $weight            =  $bikesArray[$i]['weight'];

    $bike             = $dom->createElement('bike');
    $bike->setAttribute('bike_id', $bikeid);
    $bike_name        = $dom->createElement('bike_name', $bike_name); 
    $bike->appendChild($bike_name); 
    $bike_year        = $dom->createElement('bike_year', $bike_year); 
    $bike->appendChild($bike_year); 
    $bike_facts       = $dom->createElement('bike_facts');   
    $nought_to_sixty  = $dom->createElement('nought_to_sixty', 
$nought_to_sixty); 
    $bike_facts->appendChild($nought_to_sixty); 
    $top_speed        = $dom->createElement('top_speed', $top_speed); 
    $bike_facts->appendChild($top_speed); 
    $weight           = $dom->createElement('weight', $weight); 
    $bike_facts->appendChild($weight);
    $bike->appendChild($bike_facts);
    $root->appendChild($bike);
  }
  $dom->appendChild($root); 
  $dom->save($filePath); 
}
```

but am unsure on how to get the unique_features section, can it be done via sql, all my attempts have created a new row for each unique_feature, which obviously i dont want. the only other way i can think is a separate xml and merge the two, which i dont really want either.

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Are the tables mislabeled in your question? In your current results, you seem to be missing info from the table labeled unique_features, and including info from bike_facts, yet the code shows the opposite.

Comment: yeah sorry to both, i had a nightmare trying to post the above code (long time lisetner... and all that)so it may not make amazing amounts of sense, but i thought it would give the idea. i will look over it again now and update as necessary

Comment: ok i think i have tidied it up a bit, @sloan, sorry im not sure you get my meaning, the first xml is how i want it to look, i am missing the unique features section as that is the one im not sure how to obtain, im hoping it can be done with a straight sql query rahter than having to have a second query or some sort of function. hope that clears it up a little

Comment: I got what you're looking for, and which one is the desired output. The difference seems to be that you want *Unique_features*, but that isn't in your current output. Yet, looking at the data in that part of the XML it seems to come from the data you labeled *bike_facts*, and the XML section labeled *bike_facts* comes from the data labeled *Unique_features*. That's what I was talking about. Should have been more clear in my comment above.

Comment: sorry  you were right i put the wrong table names above, ive edited them now. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, change your query to include the data in unique_features.

```
$query = "SELECT  
    b.`bike_name`,
    b.`bike_year`,
    b.`bike_id`,
    f.`nought_to_sixty`,
    f.`top_speed`,
    f.`weight`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(u.`feature`) as `features`
FROM Bike b
LEFT JOIN `Bike_facts` f 
    ON b.`bike_id` = f.`bike_id`
LEFT JOIN `unique_features` u
    ON u.`bike_id` = b.`bike_id`
GROUP BY b.`bike_id`
";
```

The in the loop where you build your XML, explode the column *features* (it will be comma separated), and add it to your XML just like you did for the bike_facts.

To get an idea of what the data looks like from the SQL query, run it in phpAdmin (or similar). You'll see a column with the features separated by commas. If your data might contain commas, you can change the delimited in the GROUP_CONCAT function. You can also specify ordering of the data.

Comment: thank you, that looks like a possibility, however i may run into some that have a comma in the unique features description. i will take a look at the options tonight and see if i can make it work (possibly escaping them etc). thanks again

Comment: An easier solution is to change the delimiter in the GROUP_CONCAT to a vertical bar "|" or other character that does not appear in the data. Lookup the syntax for GROUP_CONCAT. You can even specify the order of the data returned by the function.